# the following mail does not produce line breaks with double quotes

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am using another version of the `mail` function and trying to get `\n\n` to work but it is not producing a separate line as intented.

Here is my code:

```
// email body content
$htmlContent = "<h1>Thank-you for purchasing your Level 1 Monthly Subscriptionplan!</h1>
    <p>Dear $name \n\nThank you for purchasing your Level 1 Monthly Subscriptionplan for $price. \n\nPlease make sure that you check your student's general information to view your details carefully and note the expiry date for your subscriptionplan.\n\nFrom,\n\nPianoCourse101</p>";
```

Comment: In HTML line breaks are collapsed to a space. For your case it would make more sense to wrap each line in a separate paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html mails, you should use `<br />` to add a line break.

All html parsers will ignore `\n` line breaks in the code.

Comment: I tried using both the new method <br /> and the older <br></br> and I find that the latter does give more spacing or produce a new line... I think the <br></br> tag will produce two new lines

Comment: thanks and I hope that someone could answer my other post about the ipn simulator

Answer (score 2):

`\n` will create a newline break in the code, but not within an HTML paragraph. You can either place all paragraphs within their own `<p></p>` tags or you can force an HTML line break using `<br />` where you have the `\n\n\` code